# Crash IOS 13 and Xcode 11 in NSKeyValueCoding

Tags: objective-c, crash, ios13, xcode11

The app crashed several times after couple of minutes of use on iPhone and iPad running IOS 13.5. Yet, it did not have issues when running IOS 12.
I have analized crash log reports of devices, whether be iPhone or iPad, both of them showed the same crash in the crash log shown below:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  18

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a39bb794 __exceptionPreprocess + 224
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a36ddbcc objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a38c4764 +[NSObject+ 210788 (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 139
3   CoreServices                    0x1a4026968 +[_LSDefaults sharedInstance] + 55
4   Foundation                      0x1a3c79f18 -[NSObject+ 44824 (NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 303
5   AppName                         0x104905348 fb1UCM8vZCiE + 355
6   AppName                         0x10490d0b8 fbkUVUzGnhkS + 1655
7   AppName                         0x10490295c fbIiaWxkoUb6 + 307
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1a36d1d98 _pthread_start + 155
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1a36d574c thread_start + 7

Thread 18 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a37b0d88 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a36c91e8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 136
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a361c934 abort + 100
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a3784cc0 __cxxabiv1::__aligned_malloc_with_fallback+ 76992 (unsigned long) + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a3776e10 demangling_unexpected_handler+ 19984 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a36dde80 _objc_terminate+ 24192 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a378414c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 74060 ()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a3786bd8 __cxa_get_exception_ptr + 0
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a3786b98 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func+ 84888 (_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a36ddcf8 _objc_exception_destructor+ 23800 (void*) + 0
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a38c4764 +[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithSet:] + 0
11  CoreServices                    0x00000001a4026968 +[_LSDefaults sharedInstance] + 56
12  Foundation                      0x00000001a3c79f18 -[NSObject+ 44824 (NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 304
13  AppName                         0x0000000104905348 fb1UCM8vZCiE + 356
14  AppName                         0x000000010490d0b8 fbkUVUzGnhkS + 1656
15  AppName                         0x000000010490295c fbIiaWxkoUb6 + 308
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a36d1d98 _pthread_start + 156
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a36d574c thread_start + 8
```

But I'm still confused about this issue. Perhaps a method that does not exist was called, which was attributed to key-value-coding, but it did not find any errors when compling in Xcode. So I wonder how to tackle with it.

Comment: Show the whole crash log symbolicated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the whole log but it seems that you have memory leaks (malloc). Can happen if you are in retain cycles and / or if you for example use UI functions on the main thread.

Follow this tutorial on medium.com [how to debug memory leaks](https://medium.com/@stevenpcurtis.sc/memory-leaks-using-the-xcode-memory-graph-debugger-60de23bab3aa)

[image: Run scheme settings]

I hope I could help you to find the right way to debug it on your own.